# std::unordered_map - operator != and user defined value

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is an example code:

```
struct T
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator !=(const T& t) const 
    {
        return std::tie(x, y) != std::tie(t.x, t.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, T> m1;
    std::unordered_map<int, T> m2;

    if (m1 != m2) //compilation error
    {
    
    }
}
```

I need to use `operator!=` for the unordered maps. The code doesn't compile because `operator==` is not found. I can fix it this way:

```
bool operator ==(const T& t) const 
{
    return std::tie(x, y) == std::tie(t.x, t.y);
}
```

and then compare maps this way:

```
if(!(m1 == m2))
```

Is it an optimal solution or maybe there is a way to use `operator!=` directly?

Comment: If you define `operator==` you can still compare your maps with `m1 != m2`.

Answer (score 4):

The requirements of comparing `std::unordered_map` is for the key type to be EqualityComparable. This means that `T` must be able to evaluate the expression `a == b` where `a,b` are both of type `T`.

If all you want to do is compare the equality of these maps, you should define the `==` operator instead.

If you want to have both the operators, I suggest defining `!=` in terms of `==` like you have shown, but you can do it the other way around too.

Note that in C++20 you only need to define `operator ==` and the inverse `operator !=` will be defined for you.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_cmp and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EqualityComparable for more details.